# ttk.ComboBox Styling does not get set properly

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have created a python GUI application. It works great, and I've styled everything to my liking, save for the ComboBox. Styling on the ttk.Combobox doesn't seem to work.

That should give an idea of the material style I'm going for. Here's the styling block I have for the combobox.

```
globalStyle = ttk.Style()
globalStyle.configure('TCombobox', foreground=textColor, background=backgroundColor, fieldbackground=selectColor, fieldforeground=textColor, font='Verdana')
```

The only thing I have been able to successfully change is the text and the foreground color. I am looking to edit the following attributes:

Text color
Field background
Dropdown text color
Dropdown background

EDIT: I should mention that the color variables used are all valid hex color codes.

```
selectColor = '#333333'
backgroundColor = '#444444'
foregroundColor = '#555555'
textColor = '#999999'
```

Comment: I haven't found a satisfactory answer to this question. I've searched everywhere and cannot find answers to exactly what you're looking for.  If you found an answer yourself, it would be great if you could post it.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran in to the same issue but found most of the solution [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.htm).  All you have to do is add the following to your code:

```
option add *TCombobox*Listbox.background color 
option add *TCombobox*Listbox.font font 
option add *TCombobox*Listbox.foreground color 
option add *TCombobox*Listbox.selectBackground color 
option add *TCombobox*Listbox.selectForeground color
```

Then to change the font inside the box (when the drop down isn't present) add `font='font_style'` to your code.

So in my case I had:

```
class CreateProfile(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='dodgerblue4')
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Create Profile", font=large_font, bg='dodgerblue4', fg='deepskyblue')
        label.grid(columnspan=10, row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=5)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Background", "dodgerblue")
        self.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Font", "pirulen")

        self.list_c = ttk.Combobox(self, values=("1", "2", "3", "4"), font='pirulen')
        self.list_c.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5, padx=5)
```

Make sure you also have the following imports:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
```

My issue is I'm only able to change the background color of the actual box (when the drop down isn't present).  I'm still trying to figure out how to change the font color (foreground doesn't work for me), and the color of the box itself.  So if anybody could add to this answer that would be great!

Answer (score -1):

I know that this question is half a year old, but I had a similar issue and managed to solve it. For changing the color of a ttk Combobox popdown frame you can use the following code:

```
# these imports are indeed only valid for python 3.x
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# for python 2.x the following import statements should work:
# import Tkinter as tk
# import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# adding the options to the root elements
# (all comboboxes will receive this options)
root.option_add("*background", "#444444"),
root.option_add("*foreground", "#999999"),

# create a combobox
ttk.Combobox(root, values=["Banana", "Coconut", "Strawberry"]).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure whether I understand the styling mechanisms of tk correctly.
At least the above code works for me on Python 3.2 and Python 3.4

Comment: This solution changes the color for _all_ widgets, not just comboboxes.